# Update a table with longblobs is too slow

Tags: mysql, blob

I have a table filled with data (about 20,000 records). I am trying to update it by the data from another table, but I have a timeout (30 seconds).
At first I tried a naive solution:

```
UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a
JOIN AnotherTable b on a.AnotherTableId = b.Id
SET a.SomeText= b.Description;
```

This script is working much longer then 30 seconds, so I tried to reduce join:

```
UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a
SET a.SomeText = (select b.Description from AnotherTable b where a.AnotherTableId = b.Id);
```

but this one is still very slow. Is there any cases how it could be fast?

**Edit:**

A bit explanation about what I'm doing. Previously, I had two tables, which in my script are called `TableWhithBlobs` and `AnotherTable`. In table `TableWhithBlobs`, a link to table `AnotherTable` was stored, but this link was not a real foreign key, it was just a `guid` from table `AnotherTable`. And there is a Unique key constraint for this reference in `TableWhithBlobs` for this `guid`. I decided to fix this, remove the old field from table `TableWhithBlobs` and add a normal foreign key to it (using the primary ID from `AnotherTable`). The script from the question just adds the correct data to this new field. After that, I delete old `guid` reference and add a new foreign key constraint. Everything works fine in the small amount of data in `TableWhithBlobs`, but on QA database with 20000 rows its extremely slow.

**Update**

SHOW CREATE TABLE TableWhithBlobs;

```
CREATE TABLE `TableWhithBlobs` (
`Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`AnotherTableId` char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
`ChunkNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`Content` longblob NOT NULL,
`SomeText` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `AnotherTableId` (`AnotherTableId`,`ChunkNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE AnotherTable ;

```
CREATE TABLE `AnotherTable` (
`Description` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
`Length` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`ContentDigest` char(68) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
`ContentAndMetadataDigest` char(68) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
`Status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`ChunkStartNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`IsTestData` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Description`),
UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `ContentAndMetadataDigest` (`ContentAndMetadataDigest`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

PS. Column names may look weird because i want to hide the actual production scheme names.

innodb_buffer_pool_size is 134217728, RAM is 4Gb

Result of

```
explain UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a JOIN AnotherTable b on a.AnotherTableId = 
b.Id SET a.SomeText= b.Description;
```

[image: Update explanation]

Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21-20, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  6.3

Comment: May I know if both tables will have duplicate ids? For example `TableWhithBlobs ` have two(or more) id=1 and `AnotherTable` also have two(or more) id=1 ..

Comment: @tcadidot0 TableWhithBlobs.AnotherTableId and AnotherTable.Id are unique

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about this but have you add another index for that two columns other than the existing `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I think I should explain what I'm doing. Previously, I had two tables, which in my script are called TableWhithBlobs and AnotherTable. In table TableWhithBlobs, a link to table AnotherTable was stored, but this link was not a real foreign key, it was just a guid from table AnotherTable. And there is a Unique key constraint for this reference in TableWhithBlobs for this guid. I decided to fix this, remove the old field from table TableWhithBlobs and add a normal foreign key to it (using the primary ID from AnotherTable).

Comment: The script from the question just adds the correct data to this new field. After that, I delete old guid reference and add a new foreign key constraint. Everything works fine in the small amount of data in TableWhithBlobs, but on QA database with 20000 rows its extremely slow.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the existing tables and what you hope for them to look like when finished.  How big is a typical `Description` column?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (I have asked you a lot of questions because there are multiple possible solutions.)

Comment: Can you confirm if there is  index on table TableWhithBlobs for column AnotherTableId and AnotherTable  for column Id. Is it possible to convert the textblob columns into varchars? Also, please share the output of the following 
`explain UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a
JOIN AnotherTable b on a.AnotherTableId = b.Id
SET a.SomeText= b.Description;`

Comment: @TahaRushain It is imposible to convert blobs into varchars, they could be really big and i am afraid that right now there is no way to migrate data from blobs to varchars because of this timeout troubles.

Comment: @RickJames I hope I answered all your questions

Comment: There are at least 5 typos in the `CREATEs` and `UPDATE`.  Please fix them so I can try your code.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames I fixed CREATEs, but UPDATE is working fine

Comment: @RickJames  mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21-20, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using 6.3

Comment: (So far, nothing obvious.)  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for each.  Do you have other apps (other than MySQL) running on the machine?

Comment: How often do you need to do the query?  Do you need to update all rows of `SomeText` every time?  If not, might there be some way to avoiding touching every row of `a` every time?

Comment: @Rick James this mysql instance is working inside docker container, so there is no other apps. Unfortunately I will provide actual statuses only in monday (bacause on my local test varsion the number of rows is not valid). And I need to do this query only once, during migration.

Comment: @SHKV - Docker or not, my real question was about spare RAM.  (I approached the issue differently in my Answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts, none of which jump out as "*the* answer":

- Increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `1500M`, assuming this does not lead to swapping.
- Step back and look at "why" the `BIGINT` needs to be copied over so often.  And whether "all" rows need updating.
- Put the `LONGBLOB` into another table in parallel with the current one.  That will add a `JOIN` for the cases when you need to fetch the blob, but may keep it out of the way for the current query.  (I would not expect the blob to be "in the way", but apparently it is.)
- What is in the blob?  In some situations, it is better to have the blob in a file.  A prime example is an image for a web site -- it could be accessed via http's `<img...>`.
- Increase the timeout -- but this just "sweeps the problem under the rug" and probably leads to 30+ second delays in other things that are waiting for it.  I don't recognize 30 seconds as a timeout amount.  Look through `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%out';`  Try increasing any that are 30.
- Do the update piecemeal -- but would this have other implications?  (Anyway, Luuk should carry this option forward.)

Comment: Thank you, I should try it.

Comment: @SHKV - Your task is a one-time task?  I augmented my answer to address that.

Comment: Yes, its one-time.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing smaller updates?

```
UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a
JOIN AnotherTable b on a.AnotherTableId = b.Id
SET a.SomeText= b.Description
WHERE a.SomeText <> b.Description;
```

or even:

```
UPDATE TableWhithBlobs a
JOIN AnotherTable b on a.AnotherTableId = b.Id
SET a.SomeText= b.Description
WHERE a.SomeText <> b.Description
LIMIT 100;
```

Your timeout problem should be solved , but i do not know how many times you have to run this to finally get the `0 rows affected`...

Comment: Can't mix `LIMIT` and `JOIN` in a `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.  Anyway, what about the next 100 rows?

Comment: I believe that this is not the best solution, this is a migration script, it should work on any number of records

Comment: OK, i overlooked the fact that `LIMIT` cannot be used together with `JOIN`, but adding the `WHERE` should give you a smaller set to update, and if this is a migration script (i read: one time only script) than you could vary this with `WHERE a.SomeText<> b.Description AND a.SomeText LIKE 'a%'`, and than with 'b%' efectively splitting the update in about 26 parts.

Comment: @Luuk - The subquery approach stands a chance -- you can have another `JOIN` and `LIMIT` in the subquery since it is just a `SELECT`.  It works nicely in this case:  `INSERT INTO mapping_table SELECT rows-that-are-not-already-there` .  I dnot know the details of doing the equivalent with `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Luuk Hm, right now the tactics of splitting requests will not work because our migration script is a single procedure that should finish before timeout. Starting all of this subqueries will still be slow.